# Eloquent Nested Relation with Some Constraint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following three tables:

```
A
-------------
| id | name |
-------------

B
--------------------
| id | A_id | name |
--------------------

C
--------------------
| id | B_id | name |
--------------------
```

So, the data in table `C` belongs to the data in table `B` which belongs to the data in table `A`. Now, I want to query `C`, while also retrieving data from `B` and `A` and the following code does the trick just fine.

```
C::with('B.A')->get();
```

The problem now, is that I want to query `C` with some constraints. One of these constraints is the `id` of `A`. I've tried the following:

```
C::with(array('B.A' => function ($query)
{
    $query->where('id', '=', $constraint);
}))->get();
```

But it seems that Eloquent will retrieve all the rows in `C` without even taking the constraint into account, except when it's executing the query to retrieve data in table `A`. How do I get around this problem? Do I need to add another field in `C`, that is `A_id`, and match `$constraint` against that field?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are confusing the `with()` method with SQL's `JOIN` and that happens a lot.

### First a little background

When you use `Foo::with('bar')->where_something(1)`, Laravel will first load the `Foo` and then, based on `Foo.bar_id`, it will load the `Bar`. It serves the purpose of telling Laravel to eager load dependencies of your model on a combined query, greatly improving performance of iterations on those models.

If you don't use it, the following queries should be executed:

```
SELECT * FROM foos WHERE foos.something = 1;
SELECT * FROM bars WHERE bars.id = 30;
SELECT * FROM bars WHERE bars.id = 57;
SELECT * FROM bars WHERE bars.id = 134;
SELECT * FROM bars WHERE bars.id = 1096;
```

If you use it, on the other hand:

```
SELECT * FROM foos WHERE foos.something = 1;
SELECT * FROM bars WHERE bars.id IN (30, 57, 134, 1096); // Eager loading
```

When you add a condition to that `with()`, you are only constraining the eager loading of those dependencies, and not the first query.

### Now to your answer

To achieve what you want, you'll need to use `->join()`.

```
C::with(array('b', 'b.a'))
 ->join('b', 'b.id', '=', 'c.b_id')
 ->join('a', 'a.id', '=', 'b.a_id')
 ->where('a.id', '=', $ID)
 ->get('c.*');
```

I've included the `with()`, because I didn't know if you would need to access `$c->b->a`. If you don't, and you just need `$c` data, you can remove the `with()` since it will query for B's and A's unnecessarily.

Comment: I see. I guess, I expected too much from Eloquent to do almost everything that I wanted. Question though, what if somewhere down the road, a row in either `A` or `B` is soft-deleted? Do I have to add another call to `where()` to make sure it fetches only `C`, whose parent row still exists?

Comment: Yes, if I understood correctly, by soft delete you mean a flag on that database record, right? If so, you will need to add a `where('deleted', '=', '0')`.

Comment: @vFragosop Lifesaver. Would +100 if I could.