# How to use eager load with constraints correctly in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading, eloquent

I am using laravel4 with eloquent and have some problems with the eager loading issue. From the documentation on the official site http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading the eager loading is used in the following way:

```
$organizations = Organization::with(array('groups' => function($query) use ($groupIds)
{
   $query->where('name', '=', 'HQ_Admins');
))->get();
```

This is an example code from my application. The eager loading in generally works, I get all organizations with the groups belonging to them. The problem is that I specified a where clause like in the example code above and this seemes not to work. I did everything but eloquent doesn't register the where clause. I also tried some things to get the native SQL query and experimented with some things, but at the end the result isn't like I expect. Had anyone experience with a similar problem ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789285/eloquent-nested-relation-with-some-constraint

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do the same thing. I have companies and users tables. One company has many users.

the code:

```
Route::get('testeager', function() {
    $companies = Company::with(array('users' => function($query) {
        $query->where('email', 'like', '%koko%');
    }))
    ->where('companies.id','=','54') // Put it here in order to debug easily. Take just one company
    ->get();

   //$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
   //dd($queries);

   return $companies;
 });
```

I added a new user with email like "koko@gmail.com" and commented and uncommented $query->where condition. And it worked for me. The only trouble I had that when I inserted the row in users table through phpMyAdmin the "deleted_at" field wasn't NULL so I couldn't get this user...

It seems like something wrong somewhere else

Comment: Ok after testing again I checked, that I missunderstood the where clause in the inner function. I expected, that I receive only Organizations with name = 'HQ_Admins' and the groups to that organizations. Now I recognized that all organizations are selected, but the inner function says, that the groups should be only selected too, if name = 'HQ_Admins'. So it was my fault, because I missunderstood the documentation. But thank you for your testing, it helped me.