# Using a where condition in multtiple relation eager load in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three models

A user created a meeting and other members are invited to that meeting

I need to get the meeting with the detail of the user who created the meeting for the user that is invited to that meeting

So I have an meeting table

Model Meeting

```
function creator() {
     return $this->belongsTo( 'User', 'created_by' );
}

function attendees() {
    return $this->hasMany('MeetingAttendees');
}
```

Model User

```
function invitedMeetings() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'MeetingAttendees' );
}
```

Model Meeting Attendees

```
function meeting() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Meeting');
}
```

and finally the code to load the relation. where `$user` is the `User Object`

```
$user->invitedMeetings()
                ->with(['meeting.creator' => function ($query) use ($status) {
                    if (!empty($status)) {
                        $query->where('meetings.status', '=', $status);
                    }
                }])->get();
```

I need to get only meetings where the `$status` has a certain value, but the where is adding a query to user table. I cannot seem to add a where in the relation load. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I still cannot find the answer for this. I am writing a custom query using joins. Waiting for the reply though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer for this, so

```
$user->invitedMeetings()
                ->with(['meeting.creator' => function ($query) use ($status) {
                    if (!empty($status)) {
                        $query->where('meetings.status', '=', $status);
                    }
                }])->get();
```

should be changed to

```
$user->invitedMeetings()
                ->with(['meeting' => function ($query) use ($status) {
                     $query->where('meetings.status', '=', $status)->with('creator');

            }])->get();
```

This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this much easier

```
$user->invitedMeetings()
     ->with(['meeting', 'meeting.creator'])
     ->where('status', '=', 'accepted')
     ->get()

//If you want to do a check on another table

$user->invitedMeetings()
     ->with(['meeting', 'meeting.creator'])
     ->where('meeting.status', '=', 'accepted')
     ->get()
```

Have a look here to get a better understanding about nesting eloquent relations: [Eloquent Nested Relation with Some Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789285/eloquent-nested-relation-with-some-constraint)

Comment: the where at the end of the query seems to add the query to invitedMeeting which is really an invitation table. I do not want that. I actually wanted to add the where to meeting table

Comment: have you tried `->where('meeting.status', '=', 'something')`